# Formula outcome doesn't appear in the file details

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, json-formatting

I was in need of column showing me extension of the files, I've made one with this code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$File_x0020_Type]"
}
```

The outcome is visible in the list view, to every file - but it it's visible in the details of the file under it's column name. There is blank space there with -.
The problem this produces, is that I have next column based on that first one (assigning particular file extensions to specified groups), which's formula cannot read this first value, because it doesn't exists.

```
=IF(OR(Extension="jpg";Extension="png");"group1";"group2")
```

This, gives me always group2. However, if I only change manually, content of a file extension column and write an name of extension myself, then it works.
My question is, how is it possible that this first formula about pulling the file extension from the file can be fixed, so the second one would be working?

Comment: The first formula you are using is in JSON formatting and JSON formatting only customizes the "display" of columns/views. It does not store/save any value in the column.

Comment: Ok, so how to save it as value? Because I've found this also: 
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-file-extension-from-file/td-p/1257881

Comment: You can save the value on button click (button generated using JSON formatting) for each file manually. But this solution required manual click hence not suitable if have many files in library. So, you should use the Power automate flow as shown in the link you found.

Answer (score 0):

The first formula you are using is in SharePoint JSON formatting and SharePoint JSON formatting only customizes the "display" of columns/views. It does not store/save any value in the column.

Hence, you cannot refer the "displayed" value in SharePoint calculated column formulas (your second formula).

Also, "File Type" and file "Name" columns are not supported in SharePoint calculated column formulas.

**Possible Solution**: Using Power automate flow (similar to link you found & shared in comments section)

1. You can run the Power automate flow on new file creation or file update (as per your requirements)
2. Get the file extension from file name using the flow expression like:

```
last(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/{FilenameWithExtension}'],'.'))
```

3. Update the column value in library using "Update file properties" action

**Reference**: [Get file extension from SharePoint document library files](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-file-extension-from-file/td-p/1257881)

Comment: I'm a newbie about Sharepoint - could you please explain me how I can "run the Power automate flow on a new file"? What exact steps that's require?  If I'm sorrect, I need to choose from the drop-down menu on ribbon -> Integrations -> PowerAutomate -> new flow? And also, you mean, that in order for my repository to be working in a way I want it, there has to be other file where information is being sent, and if for whatever reason someone will make a decision of changing it to another directore, they need to remember about this file/updating it?

Comment: Can this help in any way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388566/how-to-get-the-file-type-of-a-file-in-sharepoint